# Order list according to two items

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list composed of a number of lists of two items each:

```
a = [[14, 0.5], [12, 0.8], [22, 0.6], [15, 0.2], [17, 0.5], [18, 0.4]]
```

I need to reorder this list first according to the *second* items inside each list from **max to min** and then according to the *first* items from **min to max**.

I know how to reorder a list according to two items using the second item first and the first item second:

```
b = sorted(a, key=lambda item:(item[1], item[0]))
b = [[15, 0.2], [18, 0.4], [14, 0.5], [17, 0.5], [22, 0.6], [12, 0.8]]
```

but this returns a list ordered from *min to max* for **both** items, which is not what I need.

This is what `b` should look like:

```
b = [[12, 0.8], [22, 0.6], [14, 0.5], [17, 0.5], [18, 0.4], [15, 0.2]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the negative value:

```
b = sorted(a, key=lambda item:(-item[1], item[0]))
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the negation of the item which you want in reverse:

```
>>> b = sorted(a, key=lambda item:(-item[1], item[0]))
>>> b
[[12, 0.8], [22, 0.6], [14, 0.5], [17, 0.5], [18, 0.4], [15, 0.2]]
```

Comment: Since you and w.m both answered the same thing at pretty much the same time, I marked his answer as accepted to boost his reputation a bit (you have a lot! :). Thank you both!

Comment: @Gabriel. haha. I like your reasoning. :) But really, no need of that. And you're welcome :)